# Subspaces. Valid solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering if anyone could confirm (of confirm not) that my solution to this problem is valid.

The problem:

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $T : V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Given a subspace $U$ of $V$, let $T(U)$ denote the set of all images of the form $T(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is in $U$. Show that $T(U)$ is a subspace of $W$.

My solution:

Random vectors in $T(U)$ are on the form $T(\mathbf{u_1})$ and $T(\mathbf{u_2})$ ($u_1$ and $u_2$ are in $U$). Because $T$ is linear, $T(c(\mathbf{u_1}+\mathbf{u_2})) = cT(\mathbf{u_1}) + cT(\mathbf{u_2})$. So $T(U)$ is a subspace of $W$ if the zero vector in $W$ is in $T(U)$. The zero vector in $W$ is in $V$, since $T : V \rightarrow W$ is linear. The zero vector in $V$ is in $U$, since $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Also, $T(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$, so the zero vector in $U$ is in $T(U)$. So the zero vector in $W$ is in $T(U)$. Hence $T(U)$ is a subspace of $W$.

Comment: Everything fine.

Comment: Your proof is complete. Just you attention that zero vector of $U$ is not equal to zero vector of $T(U)$ and $W$.

Comment: Your argument is correct, but the use of the word "random" is not correct. In mathematics the word "random" has a precise meaning (linked to probability theory). The correct word here is "arbitrary". Otherwise, you can simply write "Vectors on $T(U)$ have the form etc...".